# Star in sys.argv in python

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a script that utilises `sys.argv` to wrap the `scp` command. The idea, is that you will be able to run: `pyscp folder/* host` but if I run this script with those arguments:

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg
```

I get a list of all the folders inside `folder`:

```
pyscp.py
folder/0
folder/1
folder/2
folder/3
folder/4
folder/5
folder/67
folder/8
folder/9
host
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a UNIXoid operating system: The shell is expanding the `*` into the matching files. Try to call your script like

```
pyscp "folder/*" host
```

The quotes keep the shell from interpreting the `*` character.

Comment: @andy - let the shell do the expansion. you could say `files=sys.argv[1:-1]` and `host=sys.argv[-1]` and your program will work with the shell like everybody expects. hmmm... maybe this should be an answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not escape the asterisk, the shell is performing filename expansion for you. The pattern including the asterisk becomes replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern before your Python program becomes executed. You can prevent the shell from performing filename expansion using e.g. single quotes, i.e.

```
pyscp 'folder/*' hostname
```

You can then do this yourself within Python using the `glob` module and control things the way you want it.

Comment: `*` is an asterisk, `&` is an ampersand.

Comment: Both start with an a and I often mix them up.. :-)

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke `*` is a star like the aster...oids. And `&` is an ampersAND.

Comment: So I am not the only one who has to think twice before using the right word?

Answer (score -2):

The shell is expanding the file list for you. You can leverage this by allowing multiple parameters in the command.

```
import sys
files = sys.argv[1:-1]
host = sys.argv[-1]
```

Now you have a more flexible program that lets caller jump through whatever hoops he wants for the transfer, like maybe all text files in folder1 plus anything that's changed in the last day in folder2 (on a linux machine):

```
pyscp folder1/*.txt `find -mtime -1` example.com
```

Comment: Using `find` in backticks like that is very much the wrong approach -- it string-splits and glob-expands find's results, so filenames with spaces, whitespace or glob expressions in their names are liable to come out quite wrong. A safer approach would be thus: `a=(); while IFS='' read -r -d ''; do a+=( "REPLY" ); done < <(find . -mtime -1 -print0); pyscp folder1/*.txt "${a[@]}" example.com`

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Whatever. The point is that you can use your shell to select files and the find example works just fine if you know that your file names don't have spaces or shell meta characters.

Comment: When do you _know_ which files your script will ever be run with or against? Writing code that breaks when arbitrary conditions are met is nothing short of reckless; providing it as an example to others, likewise. See also entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: @Charles Duffy - "the script" was the python code (which works just fine). The thing you are on and on about is an example usage. Do you really polish everything you type on the command line to the n-th degree? I needed to find all of the pdfs in our release directory the other day. Know what I did? `find -iname "*.pdf"`. I Kid you not. Guess what - it worked.

Comment: There's nothing at all incorrect about that `find` statement -- until you put it in backquotes and have the shell iterate over its output. Well, _almost_ nothing at all; if you'd had any PDF files with newlines in their names (UNIX filesystems allow any character other than `/` or `NUL`, so newlines are certainly possible), you'd have gotten incorrect results (depending on your version of find, you'd either be unable to distinguish between the newline-separated pieces and actual filenames, or you'd get "filenames" back that weren't literally correct).

Comment: Thing is, that kind of error can actually be a security bug. Think about what happens when someone creates a file named `malicious$'\n'/etc/passwd$'\n'file.pdf`: Best-case, your cleanup processes don't delete it; worst-case, your cleanup processes delete `/etc/passwd`. Using find with `-print0`, as I showed, accurately represents every possible filename, so it behaves correctly in these corner cases.

Comment: This question was phrased as a Python question, but it was actually about a misunderstanding of how shell expansion works. As such, being accurate about safe and correct shell usage is absolutely topical.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - So the dude typed in folder/* and yes, there are times when you have to be more careful than that, but give the guy a break. It was a simple example!

Comment: Huh? There's nothing wrong with `folder/*`. The shell directly forms an array with glob expansion; contents never get re-parsed, so it's perfectly safe. The danger is with putting a find command in backticks, as you do in your example here.